# it is possible to use features maps of CNN to localised important areas in image?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cnn, image-classification, computer-vision

I'm new in deep learning and CNN, I understand how convolutional and pooling layers work, I understand how and why feature maps are created.  How I can localize from the feature maps important area in the original image? is that possible? 
I.e. I use my own  data  ( medical image ) 
Feeding those images to my neural network I can receive maps features and calculate from them the probability of each class. 
But how from that feature maps I can get know where exactly those areas are? 
how can I backtrack the weights? 
any idea?

Comment: YOLO, FAST RCNN, Fully convolutional networks. These are some solutions.